# How to access website taken down

Tags: google-chrome

So a site I was surfing got taken down. The information on it was valuable. Here is what I have tried.

**1) Access files on my Google Chrome cache**

Tried this but have some problems.

Question 1: Is there an easy way to do this? I have navigated to my cache folder (see image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RipE5.jpg). They seem to be of a mysterious file type. How do I access them?

Question 2: I used a program called [Chrome Cache view](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html) to access the files. When I accessed one of the HTML files I want, it appears as gibberish when I open them in Chrome. Is there a reason for that? (see image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZwsx.jpg)

**2) Access it my Wayback machine or Google cache**

Nope, the site went up and got taken down so quickly it wasn't cached in time.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Anrie Burie and welcome to Superuser! What is your final goal? Why do you want to access files in your cache? If you mention your actual problem, users on this site could perhaps suggest other ways of reaching your goal.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Thanks for the welcome! I would like to retrieve certain HTML and JPEG files. The website that I was accessing was taken down and I was hoping to retrieve fragments of it from the cache.

Comment: Ok, great. So then your question seems: How can I retrieve HTML and JPEG from a website that is taken down? You can note in your question description that you've tried to retrieve it from cache but were unsuccessful. Perhaps also mention which site was taken down. You can edit your question to update it.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Sure I have updated it, thanks. Is that better?

Comment: Yes, great, thanks! Is [this](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html) the Chrome Cache viewer you tried?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke yes that is what I was using. I used that to extract the HTML and got that gibberish screenshot.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47097280/1256347) work?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke thanks for getting back to me. What is unclear to me is how to even get to the screenshot your link is referring to https://i.stack.imgur.com/cavr8.png